# Facebook Messenger Handover Protocol Bot bot profile change

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger

I'd like to know whether Bot profile will reflect currently active responder.

In other words, will users see anything which tells that they are now speaking with different responder, e.g different profile icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile icon that the user chatting with a Facebook chatbot sees is simply the profile icon of the Facebook page that the chatbot is attached to. The only thing that affects what profile icon the user sees is what Facebook page they are chatting with.